# Make primefaces data table behaving like a split window?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I've a requirement to modify a primefaces datatable as the changes are made in another datatable. It should perform like the split window, where the user can type in the top window and he can see changes in the bottom window.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use the Collector widget?